# Disable event listening for objects

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, fabricjs, listen

I have 2 objects and that are overlaying each other. I would like to disable the event listening for the upper object, so I can listen to events for the lower object. In kinetic.js you can set that:

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setListening

Is there any workaround in fabric.js?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selectable: false` for this. Since version 1.2.11, "selectable" not only controls object selectability but also makes events propagate through when set to `false`.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 200,
    top: 200,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
    selectable: false           // <--- note this
});

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 200,
    top: 200,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'blue'
});

canvas.add(rect2, rect1);
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/u2kHC/).

Comment: Ok, the selection of my canvas is set to false - var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {selection: false}); to prevent group selection. Do you know if there is a workaround for that situation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Btw, make sure you're using version 1.2.11 not 1.2.0 (like you have in a fiddle).

Answer (score 2):

Update to answer by kangax.  Since version 1.3.4 you should use selectable:false in combination with evented:false to achieve that result.  According to the official documentation about the evented property "When set to `false`, an object can not be a target of events. All events propagate through it." (See: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html ).

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach by using containsPoint:

```
var objects = stage.getObjects();
for(var i=0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    var object = objects[i];
    if(object.isEditable && stage.containsPoint(opts.e, object)) {
        stage.setActiveObject(object);
        break;
    }
}
```

The isEditable property is a custom property that gets each object which can be modified.